# Basic SQL trigger will not fire

Tags: sql, vb.net, triggers

This is my very first trigger and I'm not sure I have it set up correctly. I have a table called PayTypes. Here is my trigger syntax:

```
ALTER trigger payTypes_trigger
on PayTypes
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
as
PRINT 'AFTER TRIGGER EXECUTED SUCESSFULLY'
```

I run this with a breakpoint on the first line, update my VB.NET datagridview (which updates and saves just fine), but the breakpoint never gets hit.

Am I going about the setup of the trigger incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible issues:

1) You are using VS Express, which does not support this behavior

2) You are not stepping into the trigger from a stored procedure.

I haven't tested this myself, but according to [this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165046.aspx), you need to step into a stored procedure that will cause the trigger to fire in order to debug the trigger.

Comment: Not using Express, but I was doing some research and got to the point where it looks like it is firing, but I am getting "no symbols have been loaded for this document" as a warning box on the procedure. I'm in the middle of looking into that now...

Comment: Okay, the error was a red herring. I created a stored procedure to go along with this, but am unsure how to go about getting the trigger to fire. Does it have to be called from the stored procedure?